# How to suggest a question should be split?

Tags: discussion, flags, suggested-edits, merged-questions

A few questions would be more informative if they were split into two sub-questions.

These questions sometimes already have answers that should follow the corresponding sub-question, which precludes simply editing the question and creating a separate new question.

What should be done in those cases?

This is the opposite of merging questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are already answers that reply to both parts of the question, nothing can be done. Editing the question would be wrong because it would invalidate the existing answers, which would seem to answer something not asked from the OP.

Generally speaking, you should not edit a question to remove a question asked from the user. You should write a comment, and explain to the OP that it is preferable not to ask more than one question per post. This is particularly true if the two questions are completely unrelated to each other.