# If a broad question is split into multiple questions, can answers be "ported"?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I've posted [an intentionally broad question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/11036/what-songs-do-parents-and-close-family-sing-to-their-young-0-4-children) on SE Music Fans. The question lends itself to, potentially, a large number of answers, but also to reasonably focused and concise answers, easy to browse through. However, one can imagine getting enough answers to become unwieldy. In this case, the question could be split off into more specific questions with the original as a hub.

**Can answers be "ported" to a related question in a situation like this, or would they have to be recreated at the "branch" question by the author or author user?**

Related to *[How to suggest a question should be split?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131195/how-to-suggest-a-question-should-be-split)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For better or worse, this is not possible, even with moderator intervention.  The only situation in which answers can move between questions is when the questions are merged by a moderator (or when such a merge is undone).  Other than that, answers are permanently associated with the question that they were originally associated with.

[Is there any way to move my answer from one question to another?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252936/165261) is related to this topic.